# Validate HTML form using ajax request to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to use another page of my site to validate HTML form input. If the input is **NOT** valid, I want to show an error somewhere on my form page without reloading. And otherwise, if it **IS** valid, I want to submit the form normally.

After reading similar SO questions, I didn't found any exact solution, but actually invented my own, which works for me. Though, I still think that my solution is a bit weird, so I'm asking for proper ideas.

HTML:

```
 <form id="form" method="POST"> ... some inputs ... </form>
 <button id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
 <p id="errors"></p>
```

JS:

```
$('#form').submit(function (event) {
  var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/validate/',
         data: formData,
         success: function(data) {
            if(!data)
            {
              $('#form').unbind('submit');
              $('#submit').trigger('click');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#errors').text(data);
            }
        }
      });

return false;
});
```

**NB**: It works as expected, I'm asking for better solutions.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was irrelevant. Usually server side validation is done in the same method you post to and is then returned with an error (or success). You can do this without posting back by modifying your server method and then just redirecting according to the response you receive. However your approach of validating in a different server method does not seem far off or completely out of the ordinary - I like it in fact. I'd handle the error: function of the ajax call just for good measure but otherwise make no changes. Upvoting for your approach.